# any way to implement multi-threaded access to a value without requiring readers to lock

Tags: c++, c++11, synchronization, thread-safety, smart-pointers

I'm trying to implement a minimalistic synchronization mechanism where there's an object contains some value of type `Foo`, this `Foo` may potentially be a heavyweight type, but rarely changes its value. the object may be accessed from multiple threads, almost 100% reads.

I am trying to think of a way to make this work without any locking requirements on the readers. My first attempt was to have my class contain the `Foo` through a shared pointer member of type `std::shared_ptr<Foo>`.
The read operations would simply copy-construct the shared pointer, dereference it, and then use this "version" of the value to do whatever they want.

The write operations are supposed to apply their changes into a new copy of Foo, and once done, attempt to replace the current version of `Foo` with a new one.

I realized this is not possible with `shared_ptr<Foo>` since the copy-constructor could get into a read/write race with something trying to update it, and read a corrupted value. 
I could get around this problem using `boost::intrusive_ptr<Foo>` with an atomic counter and doing the version update with a CAS operation, but there's still a race condition I can't get rid of: the reader can be suspended just before calling `intrusive_ptr_add_ref` on an instance that's about to get destroyed by another thread that lowered the count to 0.

It seems like something is fundamentally broken with this approach.

Is there any way to accomplish this that doesn't rely on a critical section, readers/writer lock or a full-blown RCU (read-copy-update)? Maybe I'm missing something simple.
Platform is Win7+/x86/x64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to first have a local `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` which has the new `Foo` and assign it to the global `std::shared_ptr` via [atomic assignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) methods. To clarify: Don't use plain assignment. From the link, you could use:

```
atomic_store( &global_ptr, std::make_shared<Foo>(...) );
```

Comment: if my class has `std::shared_ptr<Foo> m_px` and the reader executes `std::shared_ptr<Foo> temp = m_px` while a writer attempts to assign a new value to `m_px`, do I have a guarantee that I read either the new or the old value, rather than something corrupted? I thought it said in boost documentation that this race causes UB

Comment: @yonil why are you looking at boost documentation for `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: simply put, you can read from any value you want to any number of threads, but if so much as ONE write is done on it, you MUST lock. if you dont, it's UB. Now , with THAT said, there IS lock free data structures...

Comment: @yonil : From the page Daniel linked to: "*Note that the control block of a `shared_ptr` is thread-safe: different `std::shared_ptr` objects can be accessed using mutable operations, such as `operator=` or `reset`, simultaneously by multiple threads, even when these instances are copies, and share the same control block internally.*"

Comment: Alright, thanks. I was not aware of the atomic access functions. I was sort of assuming std::shared_ptr was just the plain old boost::shared_ptr I was familiar with, just by a different name.

Answer (score 0):

This would work..

```
Foo * globalFoo;
.
.

Foo* newFoo = new Foo();
Foo* temp;
do {
    temp = globalFoo;
} while(! std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(temp, globalFoo, newFoo));
```

Comment: yes, I was just not aware of the atomic functions that are available - I was still thinking in terms of the old boost::shared_ptr and the 03 standard. I also didn't know the architecture supported 128bit atomic operations, so I didn't even suspect such a thing was possible

Comment: The hard part is knowing when it is safe to delete the old object.